# RuntimeError: [blank] when trying to add a standalone table to a map with python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, table, runtimeerror, addtable

I am trying to add a standalone table to a map, but when I attempt to create the table object I get a blank runtime error ('RuntimeError: '). This error occurs when running the arcpy.mp.Table() line. The same error occurs with all tables, I have attempted to enter different table files.

This is my understanding of how to do it:

```
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')

map = aprx.listMaps()[0]

table_path = 'C:\\users\\xyz\\Folder\\file.csv'

tabl_ = arcpy.mp.Table(table_path)

map.addTable(tabl_)
```

ArcGIS Pro version: 3.0.1

Python version: 3.10

I've attached a screenshot of the error with more details.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Make Table View](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/make-table-view.htm):

> Creates a table view from an input table or feature class

The view will be added to the map